# After ATLA series ended and the Harmony Restoration Movement came to a close, what was Katara's next role?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

Perhaps I skimmed it over, but I don't think there's anything in the comic books or LoK which really describes what Katara's role was after she got married. I know for the other members of the Avatar team, their roles were explicitly stated. Zuko obviously ruled over the Fire Nation, Sokka was a representative in Republic City and later chief of the Southern Water Tribe, Toph was Chief of Police, etc.

I know that Katara in LoK now lives in the Southern Water Tribe teaching bending, her culture, and being a healing master. However, for most of her life, she must have lived in Republic City with Aang and her kids. Did she adopt a traditional motherhood role where she focused on developing cultural and ethical values in her children, much like those that we see in her? This might just be the case. Just as Katara and Sokka meant everything for Kyi (more than her own life), perhaps Katara feels the same for her children.

That's my guess, but I could be wrong. Did she also have another more professional role that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 5):

## We don't know

Unfortunately, we don't learn any more about this since, as you say, the ATLA comics or the Legend of Korra do not elaborate on this. Plausible guesses are that she may have adopted a traditional motherhood role, or perhaps as a master waterbender, she could have taught waterbending for a while, but ultimately, all we can do is guess. All we do know is what the Legend of Korra shows us once she has reached "Gran Gran" age.

Comment: We do see in the LoK comic "Friends for Life" that she's teaching lil' Korra waterbending, but this is already by the time Katara is "Gran Gran" age and settled down in the Southern Water Tribe, so that doesn't really prove much of anything besides that she is still capable of teaching waterbending... Hence I'm still concluding "We don't know"

Answer (score 3):

Your question's title asks about what Katara did after the Harmony Restoration Movement, while the body asks what she did after after getting married. The answers to those questions are slightly different. I'll go with the "after marriage" question since that lines up more with what you're looking for with her "professional role."

---

The Avatar wiki claims that she became a leading expert at various Waterbending styles and also became known as the greatest healer in the word. Unfortunately, their [source](http://www.nick.com/games/legend-of-korra-dark-into-light-trivia.html?apiKey=001) is now dead, so I can't confirm if that is true.

In the episode "Skeletons in the Closet," it's stated that she is responsible for Bloodbending being illegal.

> The most powerful and feared form of bending in the world. It was declared illegal thanks to that coward, Katara. - Yakone

She also trained Korra in Waterbending, including healing.

[image]

> Relax, I'm a healer! I learned from Katara, the best there is. - Korra, "The Spirit of Competition"

She also helped oversee the rest of Korra's training, including suggesting that she was ready to learn Airbending.

[image]

She did not participate directly in the Water Tribe Civil War but she did heal injured rebels.

Comment: Looks like the dead link was some sort of a flash trivia game, making it less than dead since the information wasn't even saved on the Wayback Machine.